# Java melody monitoring only one webapp tomcat

Tags: tomcat, monitoring, java-melody

I want to use java melody to monitoring may webapp on server tomcat. In path `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps` i hava list like this

```
manager  ROOT  SIG-CORE-SERVICE
```

If I add this into web.xml in ROOT

```
      <filter>
            <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
            <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
            <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

I can monitoring all webapps with link `http://<host>/monitoring`. Is it right? But i want to monitoring only app SIG-CORE-SERVICE like this `http://<host>/SIG-CORE-SERVICE/monitoring`

How can I do? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

First you need the javamelody libs (javamelody.jar and jrobin-.jar). Add them to the lib folder of your webapp.
Then add the filter, filter-mapping and listener (that you mentioned in your question) to the web.xml of your webapp (probably in /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/SIG-CORE-SERVICE/WEB-INF).
Then open http:///SIG-CORE-SERVICE/monitoring